# Unable to resolve "User ID field needs to be updated" error on status page

Tags: entities, users

I'm on Drupal 10.1.6, and the above-mentioned error is appearing on my status page under "Mismatched entity and/or field definitions." I had similar errors for fields on different entities (File, Content, and Paragraph) that I was able to resolve with one of the following two methods:

1. Running `drush entity-updates`.
2. Navigating to the settings page for the specific fields that needed updating and re-saving.

Method 1 does not work for the User entity, and method 2 is not available, as there is no field settings page available for the User ID field in the Drupal UI. Is there a method for re-saving the User ID field, either programmatically for via drush? Or has anyone else found a different way to resolve this error?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the same person asking at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3405944, but a core maintainer commented there.

Comment: Nope @cilefen, not the same person, but that's a big help. Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a solution to this on [this thread over on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3405944), repeating it here just in case anyone has the same issue. This problem is the result of core update 9301 from D9 being skipped (for some reason), so I grabbed the original update, created a custom module, and tweaked the update function so that I could run it from the module. Here is the rewritten function:

```
function _user_update_9301() {
   $connection = \Drupal::database();
   
   if ($connection->databaseType() === 'mysql') {
      $sql_mode = $connection->query("SELECT @@sql_mode;")->fetchField();
      $connection->query("SET sql_mode = '$sql_mode,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'");
      $new_keys = [];
   }
   else {
      $new_keys = ['primary key' => ['uid']];
      $connection->schema()->dropPrimaryKey('users');
   }
   $connection->schema()->changeField('users', 'uid', 'uid', ['type' => 'serial', 'not null' => TRUE], $new_keys);
   if (isset($sql_mode)) {
      $connection->query("SET sql_mode = '$sql_mode'");
   }

   // Update the last installed schema to reflect the change of field type.
   $installed_storage_schema = \Drupal::keyValue('entity.storage_schema.sql');
   $field_schema_data = $installed_storage_schema->get('user.field_schema_data.uid');
   $field_schema_data['users']['fields']['uid']['type'] = 'serial';
   $installed_storage_schema->set('user.field_schema_data.uid', $field_schema_data);

   // The new PostgreSQL sequence for the uid field needs to start with the last
   // used user ID + 1 and the sequence must be owned by uid field.
   // @todo https://drupal.org/i/3028706 implement a generic fix.
   if ($connection->driver() == 'pgsql') {
      $maximum_uid = $connection->query('SELECT MAX([uid]) FROM {users}')->fetchField();
      $seq = $connection->makeSequenceName('users', 'uid');
      $connection->query("ALTER SEQUENCE " . $seq . " RESTART WITH " . ($maximum_uid + 1) . " OWNED BY {users}.uid");
   }
}
```

Add this function to the `.module` file of your custom module, and then you can run it via Drush:

`drush php-eval '_user_update_9301();'`

This will update the user ID field, and the error message will no longer appear on the Drupal status page.